# Mark the 0 number in a column with red color

Tags: javascript, php, css

I have a fruit.html:

```html
<html>
<body>
<script>// Script To Request Fruit 
  function qCat() {
          xmlhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
          xmlhttp.onreadystatechange = function() {
              if (xmlhttp.readyState == 4 && xmlhttp.status == 200) {
      document.getElementById("ajax1").innerHTML = xmlhttp.responseText;             
    }
           }
          xmlhttp.open("GET","fruit.php",true);
          xmlhttp.send();
           }
</script>

 <button onClick="qCat()">Fruit</button> 
 <div id="ajax1"></div>

</body>
</html>
```

Then I have fruit.php:

```html
<?php

$con = mysqli_connect('localhost','root','root','farm');
if (!$con) {die('Could not connect: ' . mysqli_error($con));}
mysqli_select_db($con,"farm");

$sql = "SELECT item, qty, price FROM fruit";

echo"<table >
  <tr><th>No</th><th>Item</th><th>QTY</th><th>Price</th></tr>";

$i=0;
$result = mysqli_query($con,$sql);
while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)) {
$i++;
echo "<tr><td>" .$i. "</td>
   <td>" . $row['item']."</td>     
   <td>" . $row['qty']."</td>
   <td>" . $row['price']."</td></tr>";
}
echo "</table>";
mysqli_close($con);

?>
```

When I click the button, it successfully returned the table:

```
No  Item    QTY Price
1   Apple   0   9
2   Grape   9   7
3   Banana  3   9
4   Orange  0   9
```

Now, I want to color the '0' number in column QTY with red. The QTY will change from time to time depends on input, but when ever it is '0', it will be red in the AJAX return. Non '0' number will always in black. (This is just simple example that works, but my real database is more than 1000 rows..)

Pls suggest. Thanks.

Comment: `<td ".if( $row['qty']==0){ ".style='color:red';' }.">" . $row['qty']."</td>`

Answer (score 3):

I would just add the style variable.

```html
<?php

$con = mysqli_connect('localhost','root','root','farm');
if (!$con) {die('Could not connect: ' . mysqli_error($con));}
mysqli_select_db($con,"farm");

$sql = "SELECT item, qty, price FROM fruit";

echo"<table >
  <tr><th>No</th><th>Item</th><th>QTY</th><th>Price</th></tr>";

$i=0;
$result = mysqli_query($con,$sql);
while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)) {
$i++;
$style = $row['qty'] === 0 ? 'style="color: red;"' : '';
echo "<tr><td>" .$i. "</td>
   <td>" . $row['item']."</td>     
   <td ". $style .">" . $row['qty']."</td>
   <td>" . $row['price']."</td></tr>";
}
echo "</table>";
mysqli_close($con);

?>
```

Comment: If you inspect the td element of a 0 quantity can you see the inline style?

Answer (score 1):

A quick fix would be to add inline style when the QTY is 0.

`echo '<td style="color: '.($row['qty'] == 0)?'red':'black'.'">'.$row['qty'].'</td>';`

But that is not the accepted way to do it. Add a class to it when checking and then on the fruit.html page you can do

`<style>
.zeroclass {
 color: "red"
}`

Comment: Pls explain more of what u mean the other way which is more pro. Can u show it in more detail?

Comment: The best way would be to return the data as JSON from the server and then  create a table using that json data on the client. It's okay to send a html view from server but with javascript just get the data and load create the table on the client site that way you can later if you want have data manipulations and optimistic updates on the client side.  You would want your php code to not contain any view logic and handle views logic on the client side with javascript.

Answer (score 0):

Easiest would be

```
$red = ($row['qty']) ? '' : 'red';
echo "<tr><td>" .$i. "</td>
            <td>" . $row['item']."</td>           
            <td class=\"" . $red."\">" . $row['qty']."</td>
            <td>" . $row['price']."</td></tr>";
}
```

and then define 
`td.red { color: #f00; }`
in your css

**added**

`$red = ($row['qty']) ? '' : 'red';`
is short hand code for

```
if($row['qty']) { 
  $red = '';
} else {
  $red = 'red';
}
```

Comment: What does this $red = ($row['qty']) ? '' : 'red'; really means?

Comment: @P.Lau : see added text above

Answer (score 0):

give the class to row "tr" elem so if you wish to highlight with background or give color to its DOM, will be taken care by css.

```
$red = ($row['qty']) ? '' : 'red';
echo "<tr class=\"" . $red."\">"<td>" .$i. "</td>
            <td>" . $row['item']."</td>           
            <td>" . $row['qty']."</td>
            <td>" . $row['price']."</td></tr>";
}
```

and in CSS:

```
table tr.red {
  background: red;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

At the end I solved it myself like this:

Add whatever character, say 'k'

```html
<?php

$con = mysqli_connect('localhost','root','root','farm');
if (!$con) {die('Could not connect: ' . mysqli_error($con));}
mysqli_select_db($con,"farm");

$sql = "SELECT item, qty, price FROM fruit";

echo"<table >
  <tr><th>No</th><th>Item</th><th>QTY</th><th>Price</th></tr>";



$i=0;
$result = mysqli_query($con,$sql);
while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)) {
$i++;
echo "<tr><td>" .$i. "</td>
   <td>" . $row['item']."</td>     
   <td class='k" . $row['qty']."'>" . $row['qty']."</td>
   <td>" . $row['price']."</td></tr>";
}
echo "</table>";
mysqli_close($con);

?>
```

Then control with CSS:

```
.k0 {
Color: Red;}
```

It does work.